# How to draw a checkered flag to the Python screen?

Tags: python, format, turtle-graphics

**QUESTION:** Implement the following pseudocode to draw a checkered flag to the screen.

```
1.  Ask the user for the size of the checkered flag (n).
2.  Draw an n x n grid to the screen.
3.  For i = 0,2,4,...,62:
4.     row = i // n
5.     offset = row % 2
6.     col = (i % n) + offset
```

Please copy and paste the link see the ouput: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/45977/12eaef67de44c2b291ecd47fe8d10135

I implemented the pseudocode, but I need some help. I am keep getting this error: `row, col = findGrid(x)`
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

My program:

```
from turtle import*

def size():
  size = eval(input("Please enter the size of the checkered flag: "))
  return size

def draw(n):
  wn = Screen()
  wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,10,10)
  pen = Turtle()
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(0,i)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

  pen.left(90)
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(i,0)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

def findGrid(n):
  for i in range(0,63):
    row = i // n
    offset = row % 2
    col = (i % n) + offset

  return row
  return col

def fillSquare(x,y):
  pen = Turtle()
  pen.hideturtle()
  pen.speed(10)
  pen.up()
  pen.goto(x,y)
  pen.fillcolor("black")
  pen.begin_fill()

def main():
  x = size()
  y = draw(x)
  row, col = findGrid(x)
  f = fillSquare(row, col)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `return` two values, you must combine them in some way. If you do this:

```
return row
return col
```

the program will `return` the `row` and then exit the function, because that's what `return` does. Nothing after the first `return` will ever be executed. Try this instead:

```
return row, col
```

The returned value will be a `tuple`, which is exactly what you need to carry out `row, col = findGrid(x)` as appears in your `main()`. Instead of evaluating to a single `int`, `findGrid(x)` will instead evaluate to a `tuple` containing two `int`s, and Python can iterate over that `tuple` to place each value into the specified variables `row` and `col`.

The error messages generated by the Python interpreter are usually pretty informative. In this case, when it says `int object is not iterable`, you can bet that it tried to iterate over an `int` and understandably failed. All you have to do then is deduce where the erroneous statement in question is looking for an iterable, find what produces the problematic expression (`findGrid(x)`), and inspect whether it returns an `int` or an iterable.