# How to enter two parameters to a function?

Tags: python

.**QUESTION:** Implement the following pseudocode to draw a checkered flag to the screen.

```
1.  Ask the user for the size of the checkered flag (n).
2.  Draw an n x n grid to the screen.
3.  For i = 0,2,4,...,62:
4.     row = i // n
5.     offset = row % 2
6.     col = (i % n) + offset
```

Please copy and paste the link see the ouput: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/45977/12eaef67de44c2b291ecd47fe8d10135

I implemented the pseudocode, but I need some help.

**I can able to draw the n*n grid, but nothing is happening afterwards. I think I am doing something wrong in the `main()` function**
My program:

```
from turtle import*

def size():
  size = eval(input("Please enter the size of the checkered flag: "))
  return size

def draw(n):
  wn = Screen()
  wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,10,10)
  pen = Turtle()
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(0,i)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

  pen.left(90)
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(i,0)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

def findGrid(n):
  for i in range(0,63):
    row = i // n
    offset = row % 2
    col = (i % n) + offset

  return row, col

def fillSquare(x,y):
  pen = Turtle()
  pen.hideturtle()
  pen.speed(10)
  pen.up()
  pen.goto(x,y)
  pen.fillcolor("black")
  pen.begin_fill()

def main():
  x = size()
  y = draw(x)
  row, col = findGrid(x)        #I think there is a problem here. Please help!
  f = fillSquare(row, col)

main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a checkered flag to the Python screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505529/how-to-draw-a-checkered-flag-to-the-python-screen)

Comment: What do I need to change? @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's not duplicated. Just run the code and you will see!! The problem is that the user doesn't knew to formulate well the question

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Rightly said! Every time, they are marking this question as duplicate. Bloodies!

Comment: It is a duplicate. This person has asked the same question at least three times on two accounts, sometimes vandalizing the question, deleting it, insulting people, or some combination of the three.

Comment: This is a homework question. In addition, it is unclear, the user does not write what he had tried, and it complains about code not working.

Comment: Because you copy-pasted the assignment text, didn't tell us where you were having trouble, didn't tell us what you tried to fix it, then told us it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change the `input` to `raw_input` in your **size** function

```
def size():
    size = eval(raw_input("Please enter the size of the checkered flag: "))
    return size
```

`eval` handle with strings, and you was passing **int** value.

Comment: I think there is a problem in `main()` function. Please check

Comment: I can able to draw the n*n grid, but nothing is happening afterwards. I think I am doing something wrong in the main() function

Comment: Please check the main() function

Comment: If you're using Python 3, this doesn't work or address the question.